# How to prevent adding new fragments and resume the loaded fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments in my activity, I don't want to create and replace each fragment when I change my tabs. I just want to resume the last one

This is my code :

```
 private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

    if (manager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) { // No fragment in backStack with same tag..
        ft.add(R.id.frame_layout, fragment, tag);
        ft.addToBackStack(tag);
        ft.commit();
    } else {
        ft.show(manager.findFragmentByTag(tag)).commit();
    }
}
```

I get below error on this code:

```
 Fragment already added: AdsFragment{537ac664 #0 id=0x7f090098 4}
```

How can I do so?

Comment: can you try with `findFragmentById` if you have unique ID for each fragment?

Comment: Did you previously hide the fragment you're trying to show? Show only reveals a fragment that was previously hidden.